# Solving $\partial_t u=\partial^2_x u+u$ on $\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $\partial_t u=\partial^2_x u+u$ on $\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}$ with boundary condition $u(0,x)=\phi(x)$. It looks like a heat equation, but with a source term $u$. I know how to solve $\partial_t u=\partial^2_x u+g$ for some given smooth $g$. But I really have no idea if the source term is the variable $u$ itself.

Comment: How about separation of variables? Try $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$

Comment: Or let $u(x,t) = v(x,t) \, e^t$ and see which PDE $v$ satisfies.